# how to implement in JNI

Tags: java, android, cryptography, java-native-interface, 3des

How to implement in JNI this function ?

```
public byte[] decrypt(byte[] enc) throws Exception{
    Cipher c3des = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    SecretKeySpec    myKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "DESede");
    IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(initializationVector);
    c3des.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myKey, ivspec);
    byte[] cipherText = c3des.doFinal(enc);
    return cipherText;
}
```

I wrote almost all of the method, but I have a problem with the two last lines:

```
jbyteArray Java_MainActivity_decrypt(JNIEnv* env, jobject context,jbyteArray key, jbyteArray iv, jbyteArray enc) {


   //Cipher c3des = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
   jclass cl = (*env)->FindClass(env,"javax/crypto/Cipher");
   jmethodID MID = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env,cl, "getInstance", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/crypto/Cipher;");
   jstring s = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
   jobject c3des = (*env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(env,cl, MID, s);

   //SecretKeySpec    myKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "DESede");
   jclass cl1 = (*env)->FindClass(env, "javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec");
   jclass constructor1 = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cl1, "<init>", "([BLjava/lang/String;)V");
   jstring s1 = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"DESede");
   jobject myKey = (*env)->NewObject(env, cl1, constructor1, key, s1);

   //IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(initializationVector);
   jclass cl2 = (*env)->FindClass(env, "javax/crypto/spec/IvParameterSpec");
   jclass constructor2 = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cl2, "<init>", "([B)V");
   jobject ivspec = (*env)->NewObject(env, cl2, constructor2, iv);

   //c3des.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myKey, ivspec);
   jmethodID mid_int = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cl, "init","(ILjava/security/Key;Ljava/security/AlgorithmParameters;)V");
   jfieldID field_dec_id = (*env)->GetStaticFieldID(env, cl, "DECRYPT_MODE","I");
   jint field_dec = (*env)->GetStaticIntField(env, cl, field_dec_id);
   (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env,c3des,mid_int,field_dec,myKey,ivspec); //<--app crash at this line

   return;
}
```

app crash at

```
(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env,c3des,mid_int,field_dec,myKey,ivspec);
```

myKey and ivspec are ok, I can return them and decrypt in java:

```
Cipher c3des = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/NoPadding");
c3des.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myKey, ivspec);
byte[] cipherText = c3des.doFinal(enc);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Since you have already implemented it in Java, are you asking how you could call it from JNI?

Comment: I want access from JNI as I wrote above

Comment: @TomBlodget: JNI is used for two distinct but related things: 1) calling native code from within a Java program, and 2) calling Java code from within a native program. It looks like OP is asking about #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable the extended JNI checking by following the instructions at the [Android JNI tips](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#extended_checking) page (i.e., `adb shell setprop debug.checkjni 1` ). Or you can run your code on the emulator which already has the CheckJNI facility enabled. Typically, after enabling that, looking at the logcat output will give you the exact reason a JNI call is crashing.

Also, between invocations of Java methods you should do:

```
if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {
    // Optionally log something here.
    return NULL;
}
```

In this specific case, it appears you're using the wrong function prototype for `Cipher#init`.  `IvParameterSpec` is an instance of `AlgorithmParameterSpec` and not `AlgorithmParameters`, so you need to use the prototype `(ILjava/security/Key;Ljava/security/spec/AlgorithmParameterSpec;)V` instead.

Comment: You are right, wrong type signature, thanks

Comment: The lesson here to take away is "don't write method signatures yourself". Use the output from 'javap -s'. It is never wrong.

Comment: Always enable CheckJNI as well. There are plenty of other mistakes that you can make there that don't crash the application (all the time) but are wrong.